# Достать ключ по значению массива

Tags: php

Имеется массив:

```
["pid"]=>
  array(75) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [11]=>
    string(1) "6"
```

и цикл вида:

```
foreach ($categories['id'] as $value => $key){
    // Допустим, $value = 6, тогда нужно вытянуть значения всех ключей из массива pid, где значение элемента равно 6. Т-е это будут ключи 7,8,9,10,11.
}
```

Простыми словами нужно для элемента с id найти его предков (детей)

Comment: было бы хорошо получить всех предков в один массив и потом сделать: implode(',', $arr);

Answer (score 5):

Just read docs же... [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$arr = array ('first' => 'a', 'second' => 'b', );
$key = array_search ('a', $arr);
```

и [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php)

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));
```

**search_value**
 Если указано, будут возвращены только ключи, содержащие данное значение.

Comment: array_search() вернёт только один ключ.

Comment: да, верно - только один ключ - но меня опередили, написав это

Comment: @Денис Евра, да, добавил, но от чтения доков это не освобождает :)

Comment: @IOleg дополнил :) и никаких foreach тут не надо

Comment: foreach мне нужен чтобы вывести элементы не содержащие потомков. т-е проходим по каждому элементу и смотрим, есть ли потомки.
т-е что-то такое хочу получить: <li>Авто<ul>implode('<li>', $potomki)</ul></li>

Comment: @IOleg, да, не вчитался) Но не суть... array_keys() поможет вытащить ключи в зависимости от значения.

Comment: попробую сделать...

Comment: ничего не вышло. array_keys ничего не вернул

Answer (score 1):

```
<? if (isset($categories_doctors)) {

                $arr = array();
                foreach($categories_doctors['pid'] as $val => $key){
                    if (!empty($key)){
                        $arr[$key][] = $val;
                    }
                }

                foreach($categories_doctors['id'] as $value => $key){

                    if ($categories_doctors['pid'][$key] == 0){
                    echo '<li>'; 
                    echo $categories_doctors['name'][$key];

                        if (isset($arr[$key])) {
                            echo '<ul>';
                            foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
                                foreach($val as $c){
                                    echo '<li>'.$categories_doctors['name'][$c].'</li>';
                                }
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                            unset($arr[$key]);
                            unset($categories_doctors['id'][$key]);

                    }
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        }

 ?>
```

Массив $arr имеет вид:

```
array(4) {
  [6]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    int(7)
    [1]=>
    int(8)
    [2]=>
    int(9)
    [3]=>
    int(10)
    [4]=>
    int(11)
    [5]=>
    int(12)
    [6]=>
    int(13)
  }
  [17]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(18)
  }
  [41]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    int(42)
    [1]=>
    int(43)
    [2]=>
    int(44)
    [3]=>
    int(45)
    [4]=>
    int(46)
    [5]=>
    int(47)
  }
  [48]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(49)
    [1]=>
    int(50)
  }
}
```

Соответственно прокручивая `$categories_doctors['id']` я обращаюсь к **$arr** для поиска всех потомков текущего узла. если там такой ключ есть, то запускаю второй цикл на вывод этих потомков. Вроде бы проблема решена - но есть одно но - эти же элементы выводятся из главного массива echo `$categories_doctors['name'][$key];`

В итоге хочу получить такую конструкцию:
    <ul>
        <li>Хирург<ul><li>Пластический хирург</li><li>Хирург простой</li></ul></li>
        <li>Логопед</li>
    </ul>

Comment: Все - вопрос решен! Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 0):

Короче есть предположение только foreach крутить.

```
/**
 * @param $array array где ищем 
 * @param $item int что ищем
 */
function my_search($array, $item) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($v == $item) {
            $result[] = $k;
        }
    }

     return $result;
}
```

Ну и использование

```
my_search($categories['id'], 6);
```

Comment: спасибо не не подходит. пуьликую примерный ответ на свой вопрос - возможно вы поможете добить до конца